# Django; How can i change the table name used by i.e django.contrib.sessions?

Tags: python, django, frameworks

How can i change the info in the Meta class in i.e 'django.contrib.sessions.models' , so that my project can have somewhat uniform table names, but so that the functionality of the app is the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.Meta.db_table = 'my_session'
```

**EDITED**
The above solution throws an error but the following works:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "my_session"
```

Comment: @Konstant Where did you place the code? When i put it in the settings file i get an import error.

Comment: I put it in the __init__.py of the project, and so far it appears to be working. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped. I am trying to figure out the ImportError when we put the code snippet in settings file. Will let you know I find something concrete.

Comment: Basically its nothing but a folder named "management" in your app folder. This is usually used to add custom admin commands

Comment: If I ran this then surely the output of ./manage.py sql sessions would have the correct db name, right? It doesn't. I ut my code in the __init__.py file inside appname/management/

Comment: my mistake: the edited version placed inside an `__init__.py` file in my app's directory appears to work brilliantly. `./manage.py sql sessions` outputs the correct name. thanks.

Comment: I'm using Django 2.1.11 and want to customize the "django_session" table. Is it possible with the above code. If so, at which place, I need to place exactly in order to work. I'm stuck here.