# Is there any way to rename the django.auth tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing an app with Django 2.1.5 using an Oracle database. The folks that maintain the database want all tables to follow a specific format, where the table is prefixed by the project name and suffixed with `_TAB`.

I've managed to find out, that I can set the internal table name for a Django model using the db_table attribute of the model's Metaclass.
However, I can't seem to find a way to also rename the Django user, group, and permission tables.

Is there any way to rename the `django.auth` tables names?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in an easy way. You might want to propose an alternative using [tablespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/tablespaces/)

Comment: Note, Django isn't really suited for working in a world where other people own your database. What happens when you want to run migrations?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The `Meta.managed = False` flag is there for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which I found in another question relating to the same topic.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972466/2979040)

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "my_session"
```

Django accepted "my_session" as the internal table name, but could not find it in the database. Altering the django_session table to "my_session" made it work.
This method feels more like a work-around, but it works.

Comment: Could you please guide me that where do we need to place this code in django app?

Comment: I would try do it in settings file. Basically this overrides value of default class.