# Rename Django auth db tables in 3.1.2

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.7

I am setting up a new django project and
I would like to rename the three auth tables to include a `django_` prefix.

i.e. rename to:
`django_auth_group / django_auth_group_permissions / django_auth_permission`.

I tried putting the following in `__init__.py` at the project root from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972426/django-how-can-i-change-the-table-name-used-by-i-e-django-contrib-sessions/5972466#5972466):

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "django_auth_group"
```

but was getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I'm not sure this is even correct. I think I should be overwriting the model somewhere in my `models` directory so I tried:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
class AuthGroup(ModelBackend):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_GROUP'
        db_table = 'django_auth_group'
```

but this also doesn't seem to create the new table when I re-run my docker container.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly could do this if you wanted to, can I ask why you would want to though?

Comment: The other tables django framework uses have the django prefix and for table name consistency it would look neater in my database if I could change these three tables

Comment: I need to know this too. Managed to solve?

Comment: @marcelo.delta no unfortunately not I am just using the default table names for now.